# Making text bold in css

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make text bold in the last row of a specific table in CSS without it bolding the last row in all tables in the same HTML?

```
tr:last-child td,{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This works, but there are many tables and I  only want to bold the text in the last row of certain tables.

```
.total tr:last-child td {
    font-weight: bold;
}

tr.total:last-child td {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I also tried adding classes like this, but it did not bold anything.

Comment: What differentiates those tables from the others? You need something that allows differentiating in your CSS, like e.g. specific CSS classes on those tables.

Comment: Do you have an example of the HTML you are trying to style? A class does seem like it would fit here.

Comment: Add both table variations as code examples - those you don't want the last row to be bold and those where you do want it.

Comment: You need to post the HTML to which you want this to apply! (especially: To which element did you apply the `total` class?)

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your two attempts:

```
.total tr:last-child td {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This would totally work for all tables with a CSS class `total`, e.g.

```html
<table class="total whatever-other css-classes">
  <tbody>
    <tr>....</tr>
    .
    .
    .
    <tr>...</tr><!-- cells in this row would have bold text -->
  <tbody>
</table>
```

You second example can also work, but requires more control on the markup, which might be more difficult especially if the tables are e.g. generated from data.

```
tr.total:last-child td {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This would totally work for all table rows with a CSS class `total`, e.g.

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>....</tr>
    .
    .
    .
    <tr class="total">...</tr><!-- cells in this row would have bold text -->
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice answer! Looks like you might have a copy paste error though, the first and second css examples appear to be the same.

Comment: @timtim17 Thanks for pointing out! Feel free to correct next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting ID to any specific row you want and they apply the css for that particular row only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target one particular table among others, giving it and id might be the right way

```
#tableId tr:last-child {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```